# How to manage multiple transactions in SQL Server 2005

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005, sqltransaction

I'm developing a desktop application in C# with a SQL Server 2005 backend.

I want to insert rows into two tables, in `table1` one row will be saved and in `table2` more than 100 rows will save at a time.

I want that while saving is going on and between it if power fails or due to any reason program terminates then that incomplete transaction should not saved in the database; but if transaction completes successfully, then it should be saved to the database.

I'm using `Connection.BeginTransaction()` methods

```
 clsData dSave = new clsData();
 dSave.Open(); // 
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction tr = dSave.Connection.BeginTransaction();
```

`clsData` is a class in which some variables are declared like `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, `SqlAdapter`, a  var called `Connection` is declared in this class and a method `Open()`
is declared in this class which opens connection.

Difficulty is that after some 10-20 commands, `tr.Connection` suddenly becomes null, where as my connnection is still open.

Anybody can help me about this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use a stored procedure call
- Use XML or table valued parameters to pass in the data
- Manage the transaction in SQL Server

Don't make 100+ call to the database server in a client side transaction

Comment: thank you for your valuable feeb back but my problem is that i cant use stored procedure, because my application is desktop application and we doesn't want to publish our code, from which user can understand our datastructure

Comment: @Haider Ali: All code can be reversed engineered. Anyway, do it how you want: you didn't give enough information for us to help you. I told you how to do it *properly*